# what is solr clustering component

Tags: solr, cluster-analysis

I just went through solr wiki page for clustering. But i am not getting what is the benefit of using clustering. Can anyone tell me what is actually clusering and what its use in indexing and searching.

Please reply

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Clustering is a statistical technique to group data in to groups 'which belong together'.
In Solr specifically, this means that it will try to group the results for a certain query and label those groups.

This could give you additional information in the nature of the results returned. 
Example: if you search for 'Python' on a very broad set of documents, the clustering component might create groups for 'The Python programming language', 'Python the snake', etc.

Have a look at the Carrot2 demo site for a demo: (Carrot2 is the clustering engine shipped with Solr)

http://search.carrot2.org/stable/search

Solr's clustering components (Carrot2) clusters the documents using the text fields which are returned by Solr in a result list. (The fields used are configurable.)
It uses the terms in the text field to build the clusters and label them.

There is a very interesting presentation on the Carrot2 website:

http://project.carrot2.org/publications/carrot2-dresden-2007.pdf

Comment: on what basis it will group the results. i mean how it labels the results

Comment: Solr's clustering components (Carrot2) clusters the documents using the text fields which are returned by Solr in a result list. (The fields used are configurable.)
It uses the terms in the text field to build the clusters and label them. 
There is a very interesting presentation on the Carrot2 website:
http://project.carrot2.org/publications/carrot2-dresden-2007.pdf

Comment: will clustering effect indexes. and how can i use clusters to show in my search results. as i get <clusters> tag in my XML results. do i need to parse it to show in search results.

Comment: It does not affect your indexes. The clusters are generated at query time. You can disable / enable / use the functionality at any time without changing your index.
You will get the clusters in a <clusters> tag. This will contain the different clusters, a label for each cluster and then the list of document IDs belonging to the cluster. You will need to parse that.